# I am trying to decrease the opacity to only the selected element but it adds it to all Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to decrease the opacity to only the selected element but it adds it to all. I have a close button and once I click on it, I want to decrease the opacity of the whole parent element. However, all parent elements with the same class get their opacity decreased.

```
     (function() {
        document.querySelectorAll(".close").forEach(function(close) {
            close.addEventListener("click", function() {
                var card = document.getElementsByClassName("card");
                for (i = 0; i < card.length; i++) {
                    card[i].style.opacity = "0.3";
                }
            });
        });
    })
    ();
```

Comment: Please always add all the relevant code so that we can replicate your issue. We need the HTML and CSS as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that you are looping over all the buttons within an event handler, when you should be setting up event handlers within a loop.

If you already have a reference to the `close` element, you don't need another loop to tie it to the corresponding `card` element it resides within, you can just use the [DOM `.closest()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to get the nearest ancestor that matches a selector.

Also, `.forEach()` is not supported in all browsers on the node list returned by `.querySelectorAll()`, so you should always convert that node list to an Array.

```js
(function() {
  // Get all the close buttons and convert to an Array
  let closeButtons = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".close"));

  // Loop over the array
  closeButtons.forEach(function(button) {
      
    // Set up a click event handler on each button
    button.addEventListener("click", function() {
        
      // The handler just needs to find the closest ancestor .card to the
      // current .close button that is being clicked (accessible via "this")
      // and change its style. The style should be already set up in a class
      this.closest(".card").classList.add("fade");
    });
  });
})();
```

```css
/* Default styling of "close" buttons is hidden */
.card a.close {
  display:none;
}

/* When ancestor "card" is hovered, change display to shown */
.card:hover a.close{
  display:block;
  font-weight:bold;
}

/* Change the opacity of just the selected element */
.fade {
  opacity:.5;
}

/* ******************************** */


/*! normalize.css v1.1.0 | MIT License | git.io/normalize */

figure {
    margin: 0
}

a:link {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

html {
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #f8f8f8;
}

#wrapper {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    max-width: 980px;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.clearfix {
    overflow: auto;
}

.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

.headline {
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.headline .promoted-stories {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #404040;
}

.headline .taboola-link {
    float: right;
}

.headline .taboola-link a {
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: normal;
    text-align: right;
    color: #888888;
    font-size: 11px;
}

.cards {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
    display: block;
    min-height: 1px;
    margin: 1%;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 31.33333333%;
    flex: 0 0 31.33333333%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    -webkit-transition: all .25s;
    transition: all .25s;
    position: relative;
}

.card:hover {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -2px);
    transform: translate(0, -2px);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 3px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 3px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.card .thumbnail {
    display: block;
    height: 130px;
}

.card img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    -o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
    -o-object-position: 50% 50%;
    object-position: 50% 50%;
}

.card-content {
    padding: 5px 10px 25px;
}

.card .card-content .card-title {
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    max-height: 72px;
    font-size: .875rem;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.card .card-content .category {
    color: #999999;
    font-size: 11.0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 52px;
}

.close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 5px;
}

.close:before,
.close:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    content: ' ';
    height: 15px;
    width: 2px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.close:before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.close:after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<section id="wrapper">
        <div class="headline clearfix">
            <span class="promoted-stories">Promoted stories</span>
            <span class="taboola-link"><a href="#">Sponsored Links by Taboola</a></span>
        </div>
        <div class="cards clearfix">
            <article class="card">
                <a class="overlay" href="#overlay-link"></a>
                <figure class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://img.ohmymag.co.uk/headline/480/0f2af4ec6e8d3971480358d00e67e2e8117d994e.jpg" alt="3 Reasons Why You Haven't Found Your Match Yet">
                    <a href="#" class="close hidden"></a><!-- close hidden button -->
                </figure>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <h2 class="card-title">3 Reasons Why You Haven't Found Your Match Yet</h2>
                    <p class="category">Dating life</p>
                </div><!-- .card-content -->
            </article><!-- .card -->
            <article class="card">
                <a class="overlay" href="#overlay-link"></a>
                <figure class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://img.ohmymag.co.uk/headline/480/0f2af4ec6e8d3971480358d00e67e2e8117d994e.jpg" alt="Harry And Meghan Announce Baby On The Way">
                    <a href="#" class="close hidden"></a><!-- close hidden button -->
                </figure>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <h2 class="card-title">Harry And Meghan Announce Baby On The Way</h2>
                    <p class="category">Royals</p>
                </div><!-- .card-content -->
            </article><!-- .card -->
            <article class="card">
                <a class="overlay" href="#overlay-link"></a>
                <figure class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://img.ohmymag.co.uk/headline/480/0f2af4ec6e8d3971480358d00e67e2e8117d994e.jpg" alt="Things Get Seriously Real As RuPaul Cast Open Up">
                    <a href="#" class="close hidden"></a><!-- close hidden button -->
                </figure>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <h2 class="card-title">Things Get Seriously Real As RuPaul Cast Open Up</h2>
                    <p class="category">Celebrities</p>
                </div><!-- .card-content -->
            </article><!-- .card -->
            <article class="card">
                <a class="overlay" href="#overlay-link"></a>
                <figure class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://img.ohmymag.co.uk/headline/480/0f2af4ec6e8d3971480358d00e67e2e8117d994e.jpg" alt="A Tiger Collapsed In A Russian Circus Mid-Show">
                    <a href="#" class="close hidden"></a><!-- close hidden button -->
                </figure>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <h2 class="card-title">A Tiger Collapsed In A Russian Circus Mid-Show</h2>
                    <p class="category">Circus</p>
                </div><!-- .card-content -->
            </article><!-- .card -->
            <article class="card">
                <a class="overlay" href="#overlay-link"></a>
                <figure class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://img.ohmymag.co.uk/headline/480/0f2af4ec6e8d3971480358d00e67e2e8117d994e.jpg" alt="Engagement On The Cards For Jack And Dani">
                    <a href="#" class="close hidden"></a><!-- close hidden button -->
                </figure>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <h2 class="card-title">Engagement On The Cards For Jack And Dani</h2>
                    <p class="category">Dating life</p>
                </div><!-- .card-content -->
            </article><!-- .card -->
            <article class="card">
                <a class="overlay" href="#overlay-link"></a>
                <figure class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://img.ohmymag.co.uk/headline/480/0f2af4ec6e8d3971480358d00e67e2e8117d994e.jpg" alt="Attwood Hits Back At Rumours Of Dani Dyer Fued">
                    <a href="#" class="close hidden"></a><!-- close hidden button -->
                </figure>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <h2 class="card-title">Attwood Hits Back At Rumours Of Dani Dyer Fued</h2>
                    <p class="category">Gossip</p>
                </div><!-- .card-content -->
            </article><!-- .card -->
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: This case is different as I want to permanently leave the opacity, something like disabling the whole card.

Comment: @RosenIvanov See updated answer that does just that.

Comment: @RosenIvanov Be careful with your loop logic and your loop counters. Good luck!

Comment: Not only is he the best, he is a magician of a rare kind. He can create solutions without having seen any code with a problem.

Comment: @Gerard Come one, come all!